# If $K$ is compact then $K\cap Y$ is compact in $Y$ too for any closed $Y\subseteq X$

Tags: general-topology

**Definition**

A subspace $K$ of a topological space $X$ is compact if every its open cover has a finite subcover.

**Lemma**

If $X$ is compact then any its closed subspace is compact too.

*Proof*. Omitted.

**Theorem**

If $K$ is compact and closed then $K\cap Y$ is compact in $Y$ too for any closed $Y\subseteq X$

*Proof*. If $K$ is compact and $Y$ is closed then $K\cap Y$ is closed in $K$ so that by previous lemma it is compact too in $K$. Now if $\mathcal{T}$ is the topology of $X$ then we observe that any $A\in\mathcal{T}$ is such that $$(A\cap K)\cap(K\cap Y)=A\cap(K\cap Y)=(A\cap Y)\cap(K\cap Y)$$ so that we conclude $\mathcal{T}|_K|_{K\cap Y}=\mathcal{T}|_{K\cap Y}=\mathcal{T}|_Y|_{K\cap Y}$ and so the theorem holds.

So I ask if the proof of the last theorem is correct and if it is not correct I ask how to prove it: perhaps could it be that the statement is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be a topological space and $A$ a subspace of $\Omega$. Then if $F$ is a subset of $A$, $F$ is compact in $A$ iff $F$ is compact in $\Omega$.

Now using the lemma $K\cap Y$ is a compact subset of $K$. The *iff* condition implies that $K\cap Y$ is compact in $X$ and again the *iff* condition implies that $K\cap Y$ is compact in $Y$

Comment: Okay, but it seems that we have define $\Omega:=X$ what you say about?

Comment: why is that? I don't see any particular reason that we have to "define" $\Omega:= X$. The *if and only if* condition I mentioned can be applied for any topological space $\Omega$ and thus we can consider $\Omega=Y$

Comment: Generally $K\nsubseteq Y$! So I define $\Omega:=X$, $A_1:=K,\,\,\,A_2:=Y$ and $F:=K\cap Y$. Do you understand what I want mean?

Comment: Correct again! I apologize. But we have the *iff* condition is the key again. $K\cap Y$ is compact in $K$, and that's equivalent of $K\cap Y$ being compact in $X$ which is equivalent of $K\cap Y$ being compact in $Y$

Comment: Surely: it is that I want say! Anyway thanks too much for your assistance!!!

Comment: I edited (hopefully for the last time haha).  No problem! :)